# Convert hexadecimal to binary scientific notation using IEEE 754 single-precision floating point

Tags: notation, computer-science, binary

I am trying to convert these numbers to binary scientific notation, but I cannot figure out the process. Could someone please the process of going about solving this?

> For IEEE 754 single precision floating point, what is the number, as written in binary scientific notation, whose hexadecimal representation is the following?
>
> 0061 0000

I can get this converted from hex to unsigned binary:

> 0000 0000 0110 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000

but I can't figure out how to properly represent this using binary scientific notation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can find many explanations of the IEEE-754 format on the Web. In short, each 32-bit single-precision floating-point number consists of three parts (we assume that the bits numbering begins from zero):

- sign, bit 31
- exponent, bits 30-23 (eight bits in total)
- significand (or "mantissa"), bits 22-0 (twenty three bits in total)

However, in your case the exponent is zero, which is a *special case*, well explained [here](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) as:

> Underflow: If the exponent has minimum value (all zero), special
>   rules for denormalized values are followed. The exponent value is set
>   to -126 while the "invisible" leading bit for the mantissa is no
>   longer used. The range of the mantissa is now [0:1).

So, the additional leading bit is not used, and your answer is:

### 0.1100001E-126

More detailed discussion of all special cases can be found [here](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html).